# Angular 2 - Custom annotations

Tags: angular

Is possible to create a custom annotation in Angular 2?. For example an annotation @LoginRequired, where after all it checks if user logged, if it is, continue with the component. In case the user is not logged navigate to a page error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The decorators or as you call them annotations are not part of Angular 2 itself, but of the TypeScript language.

The [Typescript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) gives an introduction on how to write these decorators to decorate classes, methods and so on.

You can just define a decorator as:

```
export function f() {
    //do something
}
```

And later use it as:

```
import { f } from "./your-decorator-module";

@f()
export class MyClass { }
```

However the functionality you describe (go to an error page if the user is not logged in) is better implemented by defining a router guard for the component. You can follow the [Angular 2 Tutorial on Routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard) to accomplish this result

Comment: PS: For more in depth you can follow http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/annotations-vs-decorators/